# Laravel 5.4 different value validation rule in array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have an input with an array of entities with an ID which must be unique
I've tried this:

```
'authors.*.id' => 'different:authors.*.id'
```

But it says 'The authors.0.id and authors.0.id must be different'
So what is a right way to validate this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use [`distinct`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-distinct) rule.

> When working with arrays, the field under validation must not have any duplicate values.
>
> `'foo.*.id' => 'distinct'`